# How to convert Mono<List> object to simple List object in java?

Tags: java, lambda, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to create a POST API using JAVA web-flux. In this API I want to create a list of string and make a database call to get `Mono<List>` as a response but when I am trying to convert `Mono<List>` to simple list object using `block()` I'm getting below response:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-8"
}
```

How can I convert Mono object to simple List object?

I'm using below code:

```
List<String> paymentInstrumentIdList = paymentInstrumentRequest.getPaymentInstruments().stream().map(PaymentInstrumentData::getPaymentInstrumentId).collect(Collectors.toList());
Mono<List<PaymentInstrument>> paymentInstrumentList = paymentInstrumentRepository.getByPartitionKey(partitionKey.toString(), DocType.PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT, paymentInstrumentIdList);
return ResponseEntity.ok(responseMapper.getResponseAsClass(graphQlQueryController.queryPaymentInstrumentsByPaymentInstrumentId(baseHeaders, personId, membershipId, paymentInstrumentList.block()), Wallet.class, "Wallet"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Webflux throws a "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275027/spring-webflux-throws-a-block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-which-is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire purpose with webflux applications is that you cannot block

what you are looking for is the `flatMap` function.

```
return paymentInstrumentRepository.getByPartitionKey(
    partitionKey.toString(), 
    DocType.PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT, paymentInstrumentIdList)
    .flatmap(list -> {
        return return ServerResponse.ok().body(responseMapper.getResponseAsClass(
    graphQlQueryController.queryPaymentInstrumentsByPaymentInstrumentId(
        baseHeaders, 
        personId, 
        membershipId, 
        list);
    };
```

This is basic knowledge in webflux i suggest you read the [official reactor documentation getting started](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) so you understand the basics and the purpose.

The answer is written on mobile and not tested.

Here is also a [getting started tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)

Comment: Getting error on build() method - java: cannot find symbol symbol: method build() location: class java.lang.object

Comment: it was written on mobile and not tested so i removed the code, and not to be used to just copy and paste, you get the gist and can look up into the documentation how to return a correct server response